# adding a key value to array isn't display the key value on debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

ruby on rails

```
def get_process_order_items
    po = ProcessOrder.find(params[:id])
    ids = po.process_order_items.map { |e| e.fabric.id }
    a = Fabric.where(:id => ids.uniq())
    a.collect{ |b| b[:pre_weight] = get_fabric_num(params[:id]) }
    debugger
    wando_grid_for_array(params, a)
  end
```

can't display the key value on a. on debugger. Could you tell me?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`a.collect{ |b| b[:pre_weight] = get_fabric_num(params[:id]) }` seems to have no side-effect, did you mean `a.collect!{ |b| b[:pre_weight] = get_fabric_num(params[:id]) }`, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your are right. there is no sideeffect. But when i debug it on debugger. I can't see "a" variable was joined a key    value in it. I don't know why?

Comment: Looking at the code it seems possible that it is simply nil... Do you think this is the case? What is in `ids`? Can you do this in the console successfully?